# Strange behavior of a dotted list under some text in Chrome

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I have a strange behavior with a dotted list under a text. The problem appear only with Chrome browser (I have tested it also with Firefox and IE and this problem not present)

If you open this example link using Chrome you simply understand what is the problem: http://onofri.org/example/example3/test2.html

Under the **Main Report** box there are 3 boxes. The problem appears into the third box named **Work Supported by Japanese Trust Found**

Ad you can see under the informative text there is a list of links.

The problem is that **if I open it with Chrome browser the dot of the first li element appear on the right of the link and not on the left !!!**

Why? What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `<p id="smaller">` is set to `float:left`. Set it to `float:none`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the text above *Our work is supported...* has the style **float:left** - if you delete this style it will work as expected. Hope this helps.